# Qt+VS2010 - Unresolvable external symbol LNK2001

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, debugging

All I have is a `main.cpp`:

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QtGui>

class Notepad : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

    public: 
        Notepad();

    private slots:
        void quit();

    private:
        QTextEdit *textEdit;
        QPushButton *quitButton;    
};

Notepad::Notepad()
{
    textEdit = new QTextEdit();
    quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"));

    connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit()));

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(textEdit);
    layout->addWidget(quitButton);

    setLayout(layout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Notepad"));
}

void Notepad::quit()
{
    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.setWindowTitle(tr("Notepad"));
    messageBox.setText(tr("Do you really want to quit?"));
    messageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    messageBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::No);

    if(messageBox.exec() == QMessageBox::Yes)
        qApp->quit();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Error info:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: Unresolvable external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall Notepad::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@Notepad@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: Unresolvable external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall Notepad::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@Notepad@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: Unresolvable external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall Notepad::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@Notepad@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: Unresolvable external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Notepad::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@Notepad@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
```

I'm new to VS and Qt, Hope to find a solution to this, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that you link correctly with the Qt Library ?

Comment: @JBL How should I check the link correctness ? I'm not familiar with VS.

Comment: Right-click your project : Properties > Linker > Input. Then, check the line "Additional dependencies". Using Qt5, I have these for debugging (release lib are the same without the last `d`): `qtmaind.lib;Qt5Cored.lib;Qt5Guid.lib;Qt5Widgetsd.lib`. Check that you have those necessary for the version of Qt you're using.

Comment: Here's what I have: `qtmaind.lib;QtCored4.lib;QtGuid4.lib` Seems `Qt4Widgetsd.lib` is missing. I tried to add this to `input` and re-compile but doesn't seem to work. Any help ?

Comment: just move your class Notepad to a header file and it'll be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that you have Q_OBJECT in your cpp file

```
class Notepad : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
```

To make it work you need to manually add moc step for your cpp to compilation process. Or move it to the header file, where it's done automatically

Comment: Mind to tell how to moc ? Really not familiar with VS...Also a link on how to moc is appreciated.

Comment: all classes with Q_OBJECT macro are mocked automatically, but this is done only for header files. For cpp files you will need to do it manually, and this is probably not what you want

Answer (score 1):

You use `Q_OBJECT` in your `Notepad` class, so you should `moc` it, compile the moc output and link with resulting .obj file.

Usually, classes are defined in header files, so you just run `moc` on the `Notepad.h`, make it generate `moc_Notepad.cpp` and compile the latter. In your case you should run moc on your `main.cpp`, generate something like `main.moc` and at the bottom of `main.cpp` add `#include "main.moc"`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution for this (FINALLY!) and thought I'd post it here.
I found this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267384%28v=vs.60%29.aspx
I'll paste the key piece here incase it disappears:
To use this run-time library

```
Single-threaded (libc.lib) 
Multithreaded (libcmt.lib) 
Multithreaded using DLL (msvcrt.lib)    
Debug Single-threaded (libcd.lib)   
Debug Multithreaded (libcmtd.lib) 
Debug Multithreaded using DLL (msvcrtd.lib)
```

What this tells you is the runtile library you need, and which ones you don't.
So when I set release mode, Multi-threaded DLL (/MD), it didn't work for me, the issue was it had in the linker (under Input) the wrong values for the /NODEFAULTLIB, it had 3 entries, one of them being the one I was trying to use the msvcrt.lib.  As soon as I changed it to:  (leaving all the other values that weren't NODEFAULTLIB items)

```
/NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib
/NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib
/NODEFAULTLIB:libcd.lib
/NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib                
/NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
```

(notice the absence of the one I'm interested it the non debug multithreaded dll lib msvcrt.lib)
It worked 110%!!!

Please like if you find useful, stack wasn't letting me post for a bit, hopefully it will let me post this one.